# How to bind values using ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on an app where I am facing this similar issue. I am dynamically creating select boxes based on API response. I dont understand how to bind these values in controller. Code for reference is

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   // how to get values of input boxes here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model= "What_Should_Go_Here" ng-repeat="x in [10,11,22,33]">
<option>aaa</option>
<option>bbb</option>
<option>ccc</option>
</select>
{{What_Should_Go_Here}}
</div>
```

Comment: Try like this `<select ng-model= "x" ng-options="x as x for x in [10,11,22,33]"></select>`

Comment: how can I get x in controller

Comment: you can get `x` by `scope` like this --> `$scope.x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize an empty object `selected = {}`

**Then, loop the select boxes** using `ng-repeat`, and inside each select box, use `ng-options` to get the options for the select.

Now, **for each selected value from every select, `ng-model="selected[y]"` pushes the current select value into selected object** with the key of select tag.

So, after selecting all the selects, the selected object looks loke,

**`{"1":11,"2":10,"3":22,"4":22}`**

**Please run the below Code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="selected[y]" ng-options="x for x in data" ng-repeat="y in selects" ng-change="selectedFunc(y)">
</select>
<br><br>
Selected Values: {{selected}}
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.selected = {};
$scope.selects = [1,2,3,4]
$scope.data = [10,11,22,33]


$scope.selectedFunc = function(y)
{
 alert($scope.selected[y])
}

    
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

[Here is a working **DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/CZUsYPy9mStYUJzVBkZ3?p=preview)

Comment: That looks promising . Let me implement it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

use a select box with ng-change method and pass the model value to that change function like below.....so that you can access the selected item in js

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.array=[10,11,22,33];//assuem it as your db result 
  $scope.fix=function(val){
    console.log(val);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <select ng-model= "x" ng-options="x as x for x in array" ng-change="fix(x)"</select>
  {{x}}
  </body>

</html>
```